# Quora registration stuck at 'Interests' section

Tags: quora, registration

I can't get past the Interests page of a new Quora registration. In attempting to register on Quora (signed in through my Google account) I am at the window showing:

> What topics do you know about? Add your area of study, hobbies, skills and other interests

with the progress bar at the top of the page at halfway.

Greyed out page behind the popup window (right sidebar) shows that I have chosen the required 20 topics/interests and the next on the list is "Find your friends on Quora".

I cannot scroll down to the bottom of the 'Interests' window where I presume you would click OK or accept etc. to be able to move forward in the process.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Just had this exact problem.  Solved it by manually deleting the Quora cookies.  I have cookies from sites that I do like so I didn't want to delete all my cookies.  Just Quora's.  These steps are specific to the Chrome browser.

In Chrome's URL text box type:

`chrome://settings/cookies`

Then search for quora.  Delete anything you find with extreme prejudice.

Quora will go back to it's default obnoxious behavior.

This worked when deleting all cookies for the past day did not.  Don't know what hinky things Quora is doing to their cookies to hide from that but they don't seem to hide from a name search.

Other browsers offer ways to control your cookies so don't think you can only fix this problem in Chrome.

Comment: Not what you asked but as a casual quora reader, not poster, I'm now a happy user of Quora unblocker http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/159399